# What is a better way to trim '\n' from io::stdin().read_line()?

Tags: string, rust, newline

The code below works OK for me.

```
let mut buffer = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer);
buffer = buffer.trim().to_string();
```

What is a better/correct way to trim `'\n'` from `read_line`?

Comment: Is there something incorrect in this code for you, or you're looking for the most idiomatic way?

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, I am just looking for a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Is there anything you don't like about your approach? Otherwise it's difficult to suggest improvements, since we don't know what problem to sovle. The only problem I can see is that you allocate twice for reading a single line, and I'll add an answer how to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only see a single aspect that could be improved in your code: the fact that you allocate *two* strings to read a single line. The first allocation happens while reading the line into `buffer`, and the second allocation happens in `to_string()`.

Depending on context, there are several way to avoid this. The easiest approach is to simply avoid calling `to_string`, and continue working with an `&str` instead of a `String`. If this does not work for you, you can also write your own function to trim a newline at the end of the string:

```
fn trim_newline(s: &mut String) {
    if s.ends_with('\n') {
        s.pop();
        if s.ends_with('\r') {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

This is not equivalent to `trim()` in your original code, since it only removes a newline from the end of the string, rather than arbitrary whitespace from either end of the string.

Yet another option is to use the `lines()` iterator that yields the lines from stdin without their terminating newline characters:

```
use std::io::{BufRead};
let stdin = std::io::stdin();
for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
    let line = line?;   // line is a Result<String, io::Error>
}
```